# unwanted line between divs

Tags: html, css

I need help. I'm writting my code and something happend that doesnt look good. Between my divs i have lines that i want to dissapear. How to make that happen? Link to fiddle with my code https://jsfiddle.net/g1shy0rm/ for html. Here's my css also.

```
/* style.css */
body{
  background-color: rgb(240,240,240);
  color: rgb(20,20,20);
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
h1 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: rgb(99, 221, 43);
}
h2 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: green;
}

#banner {
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/1000/600?random");
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 150px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

#banner h1 {
  color: white;
}
#banner p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.card {
  text-align:center;
  display:block;
}

#footer {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
#footer a {
  color: grey;
}
#footer a:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. [mcve]

Comment: I think i clearly wrote that i want them to dissapear. That's all i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.card {
  text-align:center;
  display:block;
  border: none !important;
}
```

Without !important, border:none won't override the border style.

Comment: Thanks for help. Border: none !import didnt do a job. Padding did.

Answer (score 1):

line 50 of your css make it

```
div.card {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border: none;
}
```

`border: none` is the solution but to increase specificity I added `div.card` as the selector

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there's still a little bit of shadow between divs. I believe it's because of bootstrap. Without it i had no problems with that.

Answer (score 0):

In .card.scss:6

you have this code

```
  .card {
      position: relative;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
      flex-direction: column;
      min-width: 0;
      word-wrap: break-word;
      background-color: #fff;
      background-clip: border-box;
      border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
      border-radius: .25rem;
  }
```

so you should add  a redefinition of .card for border eg:

```
.card {
  border: none;

 }
```

Comment: There is still a little bit of shadow. A solution that i just found was to add 
 a padding to .card. Looks fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the following value in `.card` located in `card.scss` on line 6:

```
border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
```

Your problem will disappear.

```
.card {
    position: relative;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: border-box;
--> border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125); <-- This one right here
    border-radius: .25rem;
}
```

If you delete that, you might as well delete `border-radius: .25rem;` while you're at it, since it is not needed if there's no border.

Good luck.

Comment: This isn't possible because `card.scss` is dynamically generated by Bootstrap. The correct solution would be to override that style in his local `style.css` file, as the other answers suggest.

Comment: @trevorp So override the local style.css and do as abhiox says. I had control over bootstrap, so I could remove the value from the SASS file.